# where Redirect permanent rule need to be add

Tags: apache-2.4

I want redirect my web site http request to https 
my web site is

> https://test

my apache is version 2.4 and ssl configration is (ssl.conf) on separate file from httpd.conf 
and I am not using .htaccess file
so where I should append. i have tried on both file but didn't work.

> Redirect permanent / https://test

is that should be on my httpd.conf or ssl.conf or did I miss something else. I prefer to use redirect over rewrite.

Rewrite.log

> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
>
> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial/redir#1]  (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var'
>
> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial/redir#1]   (4) RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!=on' => matched
>
> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial/redir#1]  (2) rewrite /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var -> *ttps://test/error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var[QSA,R=301,L]
>
> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial   /redir#1]  (2) implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302) with *ttps://test/error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var[QSA,R=301,L]
>
> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial/redir#1] (1) escaping *ttps://test/error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var[QSA,R=301,L] for redirect
>
> 10.10.86.1 - - [05/Apr/2012:15:10:19 --0700] [test/sid#7ce00][rid#277448/initial/redir#1] (1) redirect to *ttps://test/error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var%5bQSA,R=301,L%5d [REDIRECT/302]

Comment: why not rewrite out of curiosity?

Comment: apache web site recommend redirect over rewrite that's all, I am new to apache so I  just follow what's written :) I am trying to learn.

Comment: rewrites are much more powerful.. however they are also more complex (but well worth the effort if you are a sysadmin). Without mod_rewrite, your Redirect statement should go in your httpd.conf file (in your virtual host block if you have one). Put it above your DocumentRoot directive if that makes it easier. You will need to restart apache for the changes to take affect.

Comment: thanks much, I have added rewrite working like a charm. quick question, is that possible to redirect directly to `https://test` instead of now I am getting a message "Found" and the link for `https://test`

Comment: For rewrite try: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` and on the next line something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]` QSA means 'append query string', the R=301 means Redirect (Moved permanently) and the L means Last.. as in stop processing rules here. Those two lines should redirect any traffic to https

Comment: thanks for the help,I did that  but `{REQUEST_URI}` recall `server\error\BAD_REQUEST.html.var` when I removed `%{REQUEST_URI}` replace `https:\\server\index.php` works but as previously say no auto redirect just give me a message "permanently moved" and the link.

Comment: You can log your rewrites to see what is happening: `RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log` and on the next line `RewriteLogLevel 9` Then restart apache2 and `tail -f /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log`, visit the site and see what is being rewritten. Just be sure to disable the logging on a production site when you are done.

Comment: I have added rewrite.log out put with my question. it's not enough space on comment.please look above.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? Where did you put your Rewrite Directives (e.g., in a vhost or somewhere in httpd.conf)?

Comment: apache 2.4 and I have added Rewrite Directives inside httpd.conf, I don't have vhost. and my ssl.conf on separate file connected to via include to httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're serving both HTTP and HTTPS, you're using virtual hosts.

That directive should go in the `<VirtualHost>` block for port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You need two virtualhost configurations for this to work one listening on 80, the other listening on 443 for the SSL. You should put this inside your virtualhost tags inside the NON-SSL site. Then configure your SSL virtualhost (in ssl.conf) as normal.

i.e.

```
Listen 12.34.56.78:80
<virtualhost 12.34.56.78:80>
Blah
some more config stuff
DocumentRoot /var/www/null
redirect permanent / https://test/
</virtualhost>
```

Just be careful about the trailing slash on the target site, if you don't have it in if someone puts in http://test/index.php your config will send them to https://testindex.php which won't exist.

Comment: I am new for apache so where exactly I have to add? because when I append Virtual host on httpd.conf apache won't start and complain ssl unable to load. so I guess I have added on wrong line on httpd.conf  `Listen 10.10.10.10:80 <VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent / https://test/
</VirtualHost> `